# Domain of trigonometric inequation

Tags: trigonometry

If $(\sin\alpha)x^2 − 2x+ b \geq 2   $   for all the real values of $x \geq 1$ and $\alpha\in (0,\pi/2)\cup(\pi/2,\pi)$, then the possible real values of $b$ lie in:

$
\begin{array}{rl}
i)& (2,4)\\
ii) &(3,4)\\
iii) &(4,5)\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$b\geq 2+2x-\sin\alpha\,x^2$

$\sin\alpha\in(0,1)$ and $x\geq 1$

$f(x)=-\sin\alpha \,x^2+2x+2$

$f'(x)=-2\sin\alpha\,x+2$

$f'(x)=0\to x=\dfrac{1}{\sin\alpha}$

and as $f''(x)=-2\sin\alpha<0$ the previous value is a maximum where $f$ value is

$-\sin\alpha\cdot \dfrac{1}{\sin^2\alpha}+\dfrac{2}{\sin\alpha}+2=\dfrac{1}{\sin\alpha}+2\geq 3$

Thus $b\geq 3$

Hope this helps